# foreign key Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with Oracle Database and I have this script :

```
create table Guardians (
    noCage number(3),
    nomE varchar2(20),
    CONSTRAINT nc_ne1 PRIMARY KEY(noCage, nomE)
);

create table Animals(
    nomA varchar2(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    type varchar2(15) NOT NULL,
    country varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    noCage number(3), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_anim_cage0 FOREIGN KEY(noCage) REFERENCES Guardians(noCage)
);
```

Upon executing the script, the table guardians is created, an error is prompted and the table Animals is not created. I did some manipulations and i think that it's got to do with the

> CONSTRAINT nc_ne1 PRIMARY KEY(noCage, nomE)

Comment: The referenced column must be a primary key or unique.

Comment: in my case the primary key of the table Guardians is (noCage, nomE)

Comment: -1. Please mention the error.

Comment: NomE : identificator not valid

Answer (score 2):

Since Guardians Table has composite primary key you need to include both the columns in foreign key.

```
CONSTRAINT fk_anim_cage0 FOREIGN KEY(noCage,nomA) REFERENCES Guardians(noCage, nomE)
```

Your Animals table would be like this

```
create table Animals(
    nomA varchar2(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    type varchar2(15) NOT NULL,
    country varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
    noCage number(3), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_anim_cage0 FOREIGN KEY(noCage,nomA) 
            REFERENCES Guardians(noCage, nomE)
);
```

Comment: Maybe you want `nomA` if that is not a typo in the OP.

Comment: @lukas irides, you can click on fiddle link , you need two columns in Guardains to be par of foreign key to Animal primary key combination

Comment: @lukas irides, what error you got also , u need to use nomA as that is name you gave in Guardians table,     CONSTRAINT fk_anim_cage0 FOREIGN KEY(noCage,nomA) REFERENCES Guardians(noCage, nomE)

Comment: but...there's an error eac time i try to do an insert on the table Animals

Comment: @lukasirides, now you need to match nomA value to be same as nomE value in Guardian along with nocage column

Comment: i did that...it gives me a constraint violation

Comment: @lukasirides, also you have nomA as primary key, in case you have two guardians with same nomE but different cage, you can't insert that into Animals unless you make nomA, noCage as primary key in Animals table also.

Comment: @lukas irides, can you create sql fiddle, that would be easy to check

Comment: @lukasirides - RADAR's code appears to work and certainly fits with how Oracle works.  If what you're doing is throwing an error you need to show us your version.